# Statement about sequence convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-explanation

I am trying to prove this theorem about sequences.

> Define the sequence $s_n = t_{n+1} - t_n$, which is monotone by assumption, where $(t_n)$ is a bounded sequence of real numbers. Prove that $(t_n)$ is convergent.

I'm not sure if this fact could not be proved from the definition of convergence, so it may require an application of the fact that any bounded, monotonic sequence converges (an increasing sequence to its supremum, a decreasing sequence to its infimum). Since $(t_n)$ is bounded, it suffices to show that it is monotonic. This is where I am struggling.

This is my updated attempt after reading some of the responses.

> Since $(t_n)$ is bounded, $|t_n| \leq M$ for any $n$. First, we prove that $(s_n)$ is bounded. By applying the triangle inequality,
>   \begin{align*}
> |s_n| = |t_{n+1} - t_n| \leq |t_{n+1}| + |-t_n| \leq |t_{n+1}| + |t_n| \leq 2M.
> \end{align*}
>   Thus, $(s_n)$ is monotone and bounded and hence converges. It is, likewise, a Cauchy sequence. To show that $(t_n)$ converges, we show (for some finite $t$): 
>   \begin{align*}
> \forall \epsilon > 0, \; \exists N, \; \forall n > N, \; |t_n - t| < \epsilon.
> \end{align*}

Here, I am stuck, because I would need a "guess" for $t$ in order to prove this. It's clear to me that if $s$ exists, it has to equal $0$ since $t_{n+1}, t_n \to 0$. I cannot directly assert this, though, as to do so would be to assert that the limit of $(t_n)$ exists.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you theorem is true as it is stated. Take $t_n = (-1)^n$. It is bounded, but $s_n = 2(-1)^{n+1}$ is not monotone and neither of the two has a limit.

Comment: As I understand it, the sequence $(s_n)$ has to be monotone by assumption. I probably should have made that clearer in the statement.

Comment: Your inequalities are wrong. It is no true that $M-t_{n+1} \leq M-M=0$.

Answer (score 3):

You have some wrong inequalities. Here is a correct proof: Since $s_n$ is monotonic and bounded it has  a finite limit. Call it $s$. By Cesaro's Theorem $\frac {s_1+s_2+\cdots+s_n} n \to s$. This says $\frac {t_{n+1}-t_1} n \to s$. But boundedness of $(t_n)$ implies that this limit is $0$. Hence  $s=0$. But $(s_n)$ is increasing , so $s_n \leq 0$ for all $n$. This means $t_{n+1} \leq t_n$ for  all $n$. Now $(t_n)$ is bounded and monotonic, hence convergent.

Comment: Thank you for the proof. Would you mind explaining how we know that $(s_n)$ is bounded? It seems obvious given that $(s_n)$ is bounded, but perhaps it isn't as easy as expanding inequalities (given that my last attempt at this was incorrect).

Comment: @Matt.P Since $t_n$ is bounded, there is some bound $M$ such that $|t_n| \leq M$ for all $n$. Therefore, by the triangle inequality, $|s_n| = |t_{n+1} - t_n| \leq |t_{n+1}| + |t_n| \leq M + M = 2M$.

Comment: This makes much more sense, thank you. As a side note, is there a way to establish that $(t_n)$ converges using the definition and the fact that $(s_n)$ converges? It seems to me that it would be possible to prove that $(t_n)$ is Cauchy, hence convergent, using this method.